# Spark Combining Disparate rate Dataframes in Time

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Using Spark and Scala, I have two DataFrames with data values.
I'm trying to accomplish something that, when processing serially would be trival, but when processing in a cluster seems daunting.
Let's say I have to sets of values.  One of them is very regular:

| Relative Time | Value1 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 20 | 2 |
| 30 | 3 |

And I want to combine it with another value that is very irregular:

| Relative Time | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 22 | 200 |

And get this (driven by Value1):

| Relative Time | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 100 |
| 20 | 2 | 100 |
| 30 | 3 | 200 |

Note:  There are a few scenarios here.  One of them is that Value1 is a massive DataFrame and Value2 only has a few hundred values.  The other scenario is that they're both massive.

Also note:  I depict Value2 as being very slow, and it might be, but also could may be much faster than Value1, so I may have 10 or 100 values of Value2 before my next value of Value1, and I'd want the latest.  Because of this doing a union of them and windowing it doesn't seem practical.

How would I accomplish this in Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do:

1. Full outer join between the two tables
2. Use the `last` function to look back the closest value of `value2`

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  (10, 1),
  (20, 2),
  (30, 3)
)).toDF("Relative Time", "value1")

val df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, 100),
  (22, 200)
)).toDF("Relative Time", "value2_temp")

val df = df1.join(df2, Seq("Relative Time"), "outer")

val window = Window.orderBy("Relative Time")

val result = df.withColumn("value2", last($"value2_temp", ignoreNulls = true).over(window)).filter($"value1".isNotNull).drop("value2_temp")

result.show()
```

```
+-------------+------+------+
|Relative Time|value1|value2|
+-------------+------+------+
|           10|     1|   100|
|           20|     2|   100|
|           30|     3|   200|
+-------------+------+------+
```